# Officially, what is typename for?

Tags: c++, templates

On occasion I've seen some really indecipherable error messages spit out by `gcc` when using templates... Specifically, I've had problems where seemingly correct declarations were causing very strange compile errors that magically went away by prefixing the `typename` keyword to the beginning of the declaration... (For example, just last week, I was declaring two iterators as members of another templated class and I had to do this)...

What's the story on `typename`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600464/

Answer (score 287, accepted):

Following is the quote from Josutti's book:

> The keyword `typename` was introduced to
> specify that the identifier that
> follows is a type. Consider the
> following example:
>
> ```
> template <class T>
> Class MyClass
> {
>   typename T::SubType * ptr;
>   ...
> };
> ```
>
> Here, `typename` is used to clarify that
> `SubType` is a type of `class T`. Thus,
> `ptr` is a pointer to the type
> `T::SubType`. Without `typename`, `SubType`
> would be considered a static member.
> Thus
>
> ```
> T::SubType * ptr
> ```
>
> would be a multiplication of value
> `SubType` of type `T` with `ptr`.

Comment: Great book.  Read it through once then keep it as a reference if you like.

Comment: The astute reader will realize that a multiplication expression is not allowed by the grammar for a member declaration.  As such, C++20 [dispenses with the need](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_typename_disambiguator_for_dependent_names) for this `typename` (though not all of them!).

Comment: Didn't convince me. Once the template is being instantiated, it is very well defined what is the T::Subtype

Comment: I don't understand the statement "...clarify that SubType is a type of class T".  Does it mean SubType is derived from the base class T?  Or does it mean there is a nested class declaration?

Comment: @PaulCyberCitizen SubType would be a nested class inside the class T in this case. The inheritance stuff generally doesn't appear in object declaration places right ?

Comment: @kovarex I am not well versed with parsing. But can it be that, when the templated class has to be parsed first, and while doing that, it might need to figure out whether it is an arithmetic statement or a declaration statement ?

Comment: Related: *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-do-we-do-with-answers-that-are-entirely-copied-and-improperly-attributed-o)*

Comment: Likely by Nicolai M. Josuttis.  What book? There is [more than one](http://www.josuttis.com/).

Comment: [ISBN 0-470-84399-3](http://www.josuttis.com/cppbook/index.html)? "Object-Oriented Programming in C++" (Wiley, 2002)

Answer (score 44):

[Stan Lippman's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/slippman/archive/2004/08/11/212768.aspx) suggests:

> Stroustrup **reused the existing class
> keyword** to specify a type parameter
> rather than introduce a new keyword
> that might of course break existing
> programs. It wasn't that a new keyword
> wasn't considered -- just that it
> wasn't considered necessary given its
> potential disruption. And **up until the
> ISO-C++ standard, this was the only
> way to declare a type parameter.**

So basically [Stroustrup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup) reused the *class* keyword without introducing a new keyword which is changed afterwards in the standard for the following reasons.

As the example given

```
template <class T>
class Demonstration {
public:
void method() {
    T::A *aObj; // oops …
     // …
};
```

the language grammar misinterprets `T::A *aObj;` as an arithmetic expression, so a new keyword is introduced called `typename`:

```
typename T::A* a6;
```

It instructs the compiler to treat the subsequent statement as a declaration.

> Since the keyword was on the payroll,
> heck, why **not fix the confusion caused
> by the original decision** to reuse the
> class keyword.

that’s why we have both.

You can have a look at [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/slippman/archive/2004/08/11/212768.aspx). It will definitely help you. I just extracted from it as much as I could.

Comment: Yes, but then why was a new keyword `typename` necessary, if you could use the existing keyword `class` for the same purpose?

Comment: @Jesper: I think Xenus' answer is confusing here. `typename` became necessary to fix the parsing issue as described in Naveen's answer by quoting Josuttis. (I don't think inserting a `class` at this place would have worked.) Only after the new keyword was accepted for this case, it was also allowed in template argument declarations (_or is that definitions?_), because that `class` there has always been somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 18):

Consider the code

```
template<class T> somefunction( T * arg )
{
    T::sometype x; // broken
    .
    .
```

Unfortunately, the compiler is not required to be psychic, and doesn't know whether T::sometype will end up referring to a type name or a static member of T. So, one uses `typename` to tell it:

```
template<class T> somefunction( T * arg )
{
    typename T::sometype x; // works!
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 10):

In some situations where you refer to a member of so called *dependent* type (meaning "dependent on template parameter"), the compiler cannot always unambiguously deduce the semantic meaning of the resultant construct, because it doesn't know what kind of name that is (i.e. whether it is a name of a type, a name of a data member or name of something else). In cases like that you have to disambiguate the situation by explicitly telling the compiler that the name belongs to a typename defined as a member of that dependent type.

For example

```
template <class T> struct S {
  typename T::type i;
};
```

In this example the keyword `typename` in necessary for the code to compile.

The same thing happens when you want to refer to a template member of dependent type, i.e. to a name that designates a template. You also have to help the compiler by using the keyword `template`, although it is placed differently

```
template <class T> struct S {
  T::template ptr<int> p;
};
```

In some cases it might be necessary to use both

```
template <class T> struct S {
  typename T::template ptr<int>::type i;
};
```

(if I got the syntax correctly).

Of course, another role of the keyword `typename` is to be used in template parameter declarations.

Comment: See also [A Description of the C++ typename keyword](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html) for more (background) information.

Answer (score 8):

The secret lies in the fact that a template can be specialized for some types. This means it also can define the interface completely different for several types. For example you can write:

```
template<typename T>
struct test {
    typedef T* ptr;
};

template<>         // complete specialization 
struct test<int> { // for the case T is int
    T* ptr;
};
```

One might ask why is this useful and indeed: That really looks useless. But take in mind that for example `std::vector<bool>` the `reference` type looks completely different than for other `T`s. Admittedly it doesn't change the kind of `reference` from a type to something different but nevertheless it could happen.

Now what happens if you write your own templates using this `test` template. Something like this

```
template<typename T>
void print(T& x) {
    test<T>::ptr p = &x;
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
}
```

it seems to be ok for you because you *expect* that `test<T>::ptr` is a type. But the compiler doesn't know and in deed he is even advised by the standard to expect the opposite, `test<T>::ptr` isn't a type. To tell the compiler what you expect you have to add a `typename` before. The correct template looks like this

```
template<typename T>
void print(T& x) {
    typename test<T>::ptr p = &x;
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
}
```

Bottom line: You have to add `typename` before whenever you use a nested type of a template in your templates. (Of course only if a template parameter of your template is used for that inner template.)

Answer (score 6):

Two uses:

1. As a `template` argument keyword (instead of `class`)
2. A `typename` keyword tells the compiler that an identifier is a type (rather than a static member variable)

> ```
> template <typename T> class X  // [1]
> {
>     typename T::Y _member;  // [2] 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I think all of the answers have mentioned that the `typename` keyword, is used in two different cases:

a) When declaring a template type parameter. e.g.

```
template<class T> class MyClass{};        // these two cases are
template<typename T> class MyNewClass{};  // exactly the same.
```

Which there is no difference between them and they are EXACTLY the same.

b) Before using a ***nested dependent type name*** for a template.

```
template<class T>
void foo(const T & param)
{
   typename T::NestedType * value; // we should use typename here
}
```

Which not using `typename` leads to parsing/compilation errors.

What I want to add to the second case, as mentioned in Scot Meyers book [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876), is that there is an exception of using `typename` before a ***nested dependant type name***. The exception is that if you use the ***nested dependant type name*** either as a *base class* or in a *member initialization list*, you should not use `typename` there:

```
template<class T>
class D : public B<T>::NestedType               // No need for typename here
{
public:
   D(std::string str) : B<T>::NestedType(str)   // No need for typename here
   {
      typename B<T>::AnotherNestedType * x;     // typename is needed here
   }
}
```

**Note:** Using `typename` for the second case (i.e. before nested dependent type name) is not needed since C++20.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    typedef int my_t;
};

template <class T>
class B {
public:
    // T::my_t *ptr; // It will produce compilation error
    typename T::my_t *ptr; // It will output 5
};

int main() {
    B<A> b;
    int my_int = 5;
    b.ptr = &my_int;
    std::cout << *b.ptr;
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```