# C++, what does this syntax mean?

Tags: c++, templates

i found this in this file: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/phoenix/core/actor.hpp

What does this syntax means?

```
struct actor ... {
        ...
        template <typename T0, typename T1>
        typename result<actor(T0&,T1&)>::type // this line
```

I know what typename and templates are, my question is about `actor(T0&,T1&)` syntax

thank you

Comment: See [Officially, what is typename for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600936/officially-what-is-typename-for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this means that there is a template called `result` and within result is a type called `type`.

```
template <class T>
class result
{
public:
    typedef ... type;
};
```

So that line is using that type from the template.

Because the compiler does not know what `result<actor(T0&,T1&)>::type` is, you need to use `typename` to tell the compiler to treat it as a type.

**Update**

`actor(T0&,T1&)` is a function taking a `T0&` and a `T1&` and returning an `actor` by value.

Comment: what does this mean `actor(T0&,T1&)`?

Comment: @aaa - a function taking a `T0` and `T1` both by reference and returning an `actor` by value.

Comment: thank you.
I am actually somewhat familiar with function/function pointer syntax, but I have never seen it as template parameter.

Comment: @aaa to clarify, it's not somehow a function *call* (as it looks quite similar), but it's the *type* of a function.

Answer (score 3):

The full declaration from that file reads:

```
template <typename T0, typename T1>
typename result<actor(T0&,T1&)>::type
operator()(T0& _0, T1& _1) const
{
    /* snip */
}
```

If you break it down into chunks, it's easier to read:

```
template <typename T0, typename T1>
```

It's a template...

```
operator()(...) const
```

...a templated function-call operator function...

```
operator()(T0& _0, T1& _1) const
```

...which takes two arguments, by reference, of type `T0` and `T1`...

```
typename result<...>::type
```

...and returns a result whose type is the `type` member of `result`...

```
typename result<actor(T0&,T1&)>::type
```

...where the type of `result` is paramaterised by the expression `actor(T0&,T1&)`.