# What is the purpose of "typename" in C++

Tags: c++, templates, typename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Officially, what is typename for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600936/officially-what-is-typename-for)

When I use

```
template <typename TMap>
typename TMap::referent_type * func(TMap & map, typename TMap::key_type key) 
{ ... }
```

what is the purpose of the two "typename"'s on the second line?

It seems to trigger a compile-time warning (VS2008: [C4346](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsx7wabs(VS.80).aspx)) but it's only a "do you claim this to be a type"?

i.e. the actual check if `TMap::referent_type` is actually type is made when the template gets instantiated, but there still seems to be a requirement by the C++ standard, but the code being parsed correctly regarless.

Are there any examples where the typename is actually required to resolve an ambiguity? Or is there more to that?

Comment: I must admit to be slightly surprised that a person with the C++ tag would ask such a basic question about template programming. Have you ever compiled with a better compiler than Visual Studio ? (as in, more compliant to the standard)

Comment: @Mathieu: I've used Watcom C++ 9.0-10.5, "watching" the finer details of C++ come to life in it, and I've used Comeau for some tests - though never in production. Is dissing of VS really deserved here? --- The key insight I was missing was that `T::SubType * p` would get parsed as arithmetic expression. --- I didn't note that I have a C++ tag, but I do know that C++ still surprises me roughly once a month.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `typename` keyword just tells the compiler that whatever identifier follows is a valid type.  This is important in templates because the compiler may not yet have the definitions of the types used in the templates, but you still want to be able to use part of that type's definition (e.g., like `key_type` above).  If you didn't use the `typename` keyword, the compiler would error out on that symbol because it doesn't know what it is.  This comes in to play often when you use template instances as template parameters.

Clear as mud?

Comment: +1 - To (hopefully) clarify a little, within a template, if you have  Shape::type, the compiler can't discern if type is a "type" or if it's a variable/enum within Shape.  Using the typename qualifier allows you to tell the compiler that this is a "type".

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `typename` when the type which you are using is depended to another thing.

In your example, `TMap::key_type` is depended to the template argument and `TMap::key_type` may be a function identifier or a variable name or anything else... so we have to ensure the compiler that is a type not a member function/variable.

On the other hand, when the type which we are using are not depended on another templates, then we don't need to specify that as a `typename`.