# Odd error with C++ class template

Tags: c++

can anyone suggest why this does not compile? I guess I'm missing something major here. The compiler is g++ 4.2.1 (on OS X) and error is "expected `;' before ‘it’" on the line where the iterator is declared.

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class A {
public:
    struct SomeStruct {
        T* ptr;
        int i;
    };

    typedef std::vector<SomeStruct> MyList;

    void Func()
    {
        MyList::iterator it;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes you are missing something major: telling us what the compiler error is. :)

Comment: @Steve: No, the compiler doesn't matter, except the g++ incorrectly accepts the code.

Comment: Yep, sorry 'bout that. Edited.

Comment: FYI: Visual studio 2010 accepts this code without complaints.

Comment: @Alf: What version of gcc? I have both 4.3.4 and 4.4.3, and both reject the above. Also, Steve's point was that if you're going to post a segment of code and claim it doesn't compile, starting your readers off with the compiler error is good form.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600936/officially-what-is-typename-for

Comment: @MaR: VC still doesn't do proper two-phase lookup (12 years after it was standardized, even longer since it was thought up) and therefore accepts faulty code.

Comment: @Thanatos: my bad, it was MSVC 10.0 that incorrectly accepted the code. Cheers, & thanks,

Answer (score 6):

Change:

```
MyList::iterator it;
```

to:

```
typename MyList::iterator it;
```

I believe this has to do with the compiler not being sure as to whether `MyList::iterator` should be a value of some sort (say that `iterator` was a static member of `MyList`) or a type. `typename` forces the latter (correct) option.

I believe the relevant standard quoting starts here, second 14.6:

> A name used in a template is assumed not to name a type unless the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified by the keyword `typename`.

So, you'd have to figure out what the "applicable name lookup" is, but the standard also follows up with this example:

```
// no B declared here

class X;

template<class T> class Y {
    class Z; // forward declaration of member class

    void f() {
        X* a1;     // declare pointer to X
        T* a2;     // declare pointer to T
        Y* a3;     // declare pointer to Y<T>
        Z* a4;     // declare pointer to Z
        typedef typename T::A TA;
        TA* a5;    // declare pointer to T’s A
        typename T::A* a6;  // declare pointer to T’s A
        T::A* a7;  // T::A is not a type name:
                   // multiply T::A by a7
        B* a8;     // B is not a type name:
                   // multiply B by a8; ill-formed,
                   // no visible declaration of B
        }
};
```

Comment: No, `typename` is **not** required here!

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: I compiled his code locally before posting this: The addition of `typename` fixes the compiler error ("expected `;' before ‘it’")

Comment: @Thanatos, @Alf: Apparently I was wrong but I still don't get it how SomeStruct is a dependent name...

Comment: @Armen: depending on the `t` in `A<t>::SomeStruct`, the `SomeStruct` is a different type. Concretely, in one case it's a struct that contains an `int` pointer, say, and in another it contains a `double` pointer, so on. But what matters is that `std::vector` (from the compiler's point of view, it's not practically possible!) might be specialized for one of those variants. Where that specialization might not have the `iterator` type member, or might have some other kind of member named `iterator`. Now I can't see any example where that could actually happen. But it's from general rules. Cheers,

Comment: @Thanatos: re your last edit, it has nothing to do with whether `SomeStruct` is recognized as a type. It is recognized as a type. The code requires a `typename` keyword because the specialization of `vector` depends on `SomeStruct` which depends on the template parameter `T`. I.e. we're talking about *dependent names* here. As I recall there's a FAQ item about just that, if so good starting point. Cheers,

Answer (score 4):

You're lacking a `typename`:

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class A {
public:
    struct SomeStruct {
        T* ptr;
        int i;
    };

    typedef std::vector<SomeStruct> MyList;

    void Func()
    {
        typename MyList::iterator it;
    }
};

int main() {}
```

This code compiles with g++, msvc and Comeau Online.

Technically `SomeStruct` is a *dependent name*, meaning that what `SomeStruct` stands for depends on the template parameter. From the compiler's point of view `std::vector` might be specialized for some `A<T>::SomeStruct`, where that specialization doesn't have an `iterator` typedef. So you have to *tell* the poor compiler. ;-)

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Phew, makes sense. Didn't get one of those before. Thanks Alf.