# How to use an stl container's size_type type when using templates?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to use the size_type from std::list and I have the following list:

```
std::list<T*> mylist;

template <class T>
T* at(std::list<T*>::size_type pos);
```

But this doesn't work as I get a bunch of syntax errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <class T> T*
at(typename std::list<T*>::size_type pos);
// ^^^^^^^^
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600936/officially-what-is-typename-for).

Answer (score 1):

Add `typename` ala:

```
template <class T>
T* at(typename std::list<T*>::size_type pos);
```

Otherwise, the compiler doesn't know what size_type could be.

Comment: it could guess, and suggest it, but it's lazy :(

Comment: @Matthieu: suggest it in the error message?  True.  Still, historically many compilers used to guess and not have an error, but the Standard chose not to follow that precedent and compiler Standards compliance has tightened up. I formed the impression that there were some practical issues behind it though, allowing slightly better checks when the compiler first parses the template and before any specific instantiation, rather than it being simple laziness. Can't remember any actual examples though - might have to dig through old comp.lang.c++.moderated posts for such....

Comment: that's what warnings are for - Standard compliant and you can still do the right thing.  It's not rocket science here, given that many compilers could compile it in the past.

Comment: @MSalters: actually, with two-phase look-up it's much more complicated. VC++ accept it because it does not implement the standard two-phases look-up. icc, gcc, CLang will all reject it. However it does seem rather easy to guess (at least in simple situations) when it *should* have been prefixed by either `typename` or `template` and deliver the appropriate note next to the error to help the user fix its code. If I ever get Clang to work on my windows machine, I've promised myself to poke around this issue :)