# Typedef inside template class doesn't work

Tags: c++, class, templates, typedef, typename

I have a problem with the following code:

```
template <typename U>
class lamePtr
{
public:
    typedef U* ptr;
};

template <typename U>
class smarterPointer
{
    public:
    void funFun()
    {
        typedef lamePtr<U> someType;
        someType::ptr query;
    }
};
```

As you see, I have a typedef inside lamePtr. Inside smarterPointer class I have a function funFun(). What am I trying to do is to make another typedef someType. Till that line, everything works fine until we get to the line with someType::ptr query.

What I want here to happen is that "query" will become lamePtr< U >::ptr (a simple value, not a typedef ;). However, I get compilation errors (with gcc 4.4.3):

```
temp.cpp: In member function ‘void smarterPointer<U>::funFun()’:
temp.cpp:15: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘query’
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Related, with lots of information about why the `typename` is needed:  [Where and why do I have to put `template` and `typename` on dependent names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names)

Comment: In the future, don't try to format your code with html tags.  Just enter it as is, select it all, and click the `{}` button.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind for the future. Thanks for the reference James, I will spend some time on that

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`someType`, as `lamePtr<U>` is a "dependant name". It depends on what `U` is as to whether or not there is a member `ptr` and, if so, what kind of "thing" that member is.

Of course, *you* know that for all `T`, `lamePtr<T>::ptr` is a type, but at this stage of compilation the parser does not know that.

Use [the `typename` keyword](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html) to hint to the parser that it's a type. The rest will be resolved later in the compilation process. Just a little C++ quirk.

```
template <typename U>
class lamePtr
{
public:
    typedef U* ptr;
};

template <typename U>
class smarterPointer
{
    public:
    void funFun()
    {
        typedef lamePtr<U> someType;
        typename someType::ptr query;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 9):

You need the `typename` keyword to signify that `someType::ptr` is a type.

```
    typename someType::ptr query;
```

See [Officially, what is typename for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600936/officially-what-is-typename-for) for detail.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I will certainly have to read more about typenames, thanks for the solution and the link

Comment: @Melon : Some further reading material if you're interested: http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#typename