# C++: Return pointer to template subclass

Tags: c++, templates

What is the syntax for doing something  like this? When I try to compile the code below it tells me that `a ';' was expected before '*'`, pointing to the return type of the function, `ResourceManager<T>::ResourceWrapper*`.

```
template<class T>
class ResourceManager
{
  private:
    struct ResourceWrapper;
    ResourceWrapper* pushNewResource(const std::string& file);
};

// (Definition of ResourceWrapper not shown.)

template <class T>
ResourceManager<T>::ResourceWrapper* ResourceManager<T>::pushNewResource(
    const std::string& file)
{
    // (Irrelevant details)
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing the `typename` keyword. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600936/officially-what-is-typename-for) for more details on why `typename` is required. This code should compile:

```
template<class T>
class ResourceManager
{
  private:
    struct ResourceWrapper;
    ResourceWrapper* pushNewResource(const std::string& file);
};

// (Definition of ResourceWrapper not shown.)

template <class T>
typename ResourceManager<T>::ResourceWrapper* ResourceManager<T>::pushNewResource(
^^^^^^^^    const std::string& file)
{
    // (Irrelevant details)
}
```