# Reason for requiring typename in a template definition

Tags: c++, typename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put “template” and “typename” on dependent names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names)

This is a specific instance of the question: [Officially, what is typename for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600936/officially-what-is-typename-for)

I am asking for the specific reason that the compiler is NOT aware that the following is a type:

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>    // T is a type, right?
void f(const char name[], const std::vector<T>& foo) // typename NOT needed here
{
  for(std::set<T>::iterator itr =  // here, it is needed
```

If I declare:

```
std::set<int>::iterator itr; // no problem
```

The above clearly defines that `T` is a type, so why is `typename` required in one and not the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you've links to a thorough answer, it's a lot to wade through.  So - put as simply as I can - the point is that the compiler does indeed know that `T` is a type as you say, but using that information and even having seen the included source code for `std::set`, it can't be sure whether the `iterator` identifier inside the `set<T>` will name a type, a function, or a variable.  This might seem surprising as if you look at the `set<>` template you can work it out, but remember that somewhere between the compiler parsing your `f<>()` template and before it's instantiated, a specialisation for `set<T>` may be specified that uses identifier for a non-type, or simply lacks it altogether.

So, the `typename` keyword just tells the compiler, hey - whatever happens you can expect `iterator` to name a type, and perform some validatition of the `f<>()` template code on that basis without waiting to see an instantiation.

Comment: thanks!  I also noticed that I don't know how to escape angle brackets in a question....  I wonder if &lt; &gt; will do it...

Comment: +1 for this : *"on that basis without waiting to see an instantiation."*.

Comment: @Dov: that stuff's tricky at first... just use back ticks (left single quotes) around source code mixed into normal text, and when you've got a whole line or block of source code just leave a blank line before and after and make sure it's indented by four or more spaces....  Cheers.