# Sort and find functions in the generic linked list

Tags: c++

This is my code after lots of changes that I did.I have a problem with to functions (sort and find) but I still can't understand how to solve it.

```
using namespace std;    
using namespace ListExceptions;

template <typename T> class Node;
template <typename T> class Iterator;

/*List class*/
template <typename T>
class List{
private:
Node<T> * first;
Node<T> * last;
int size;
friend class Predicate;
friend class Compare;
public:
typedef Iterator<T> iterator;
List(){
   first = NULL;
   last = NULL;
   size = 0;
}
List(const List<T> & l);
void pushBack(T element);
void insert( const T& element, iterator i);
iterator remove(iterator i);

iterator find(const Predicate& predicate(const T element));//line 47
void sort(const Compare& comparer());//line 48

int getSize() const;
iterator begin();
iterator end();
~List();
};

/*Implimentation of List functions*/
template <class T>
List<T>::List(const List & l) {
first = 0;
last = 0;
size = 0;
for (Node<T> * current = l.first; current != 0; current = current -> next){
    pushBack(current -> data);
}
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::pushBack(T element){
Node<T>* newnode = new Node<T>(element);
if (newnode->prev == NULL) {
  first = newnode;
  last = newnode;
}else{
  newnode->prev = last;
  last->next = newnode;
  last = newnode;
}
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::insert( const T& element, iterator i){
if (i.position == NULL){
  pushBack(element);
  ++size;
  return;
}
Node<T>* after = i.position;
Node<T>* before =  after->prev;
Node<T>* newnode = new Node<T>(element);
newnode->prev = before;
newnode->next = after;
after->prev = newnode;
if (before == NULL) {
  first = newnode;
}
else{
  before->next = newnode;
}
++size;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::remove(iterator iter){
  if(iter.position != NULL){
      Node<T>* remove = iter.position;
       Node<T>* before = remove->prev;
       Node<T>* after = remove->next;
       if (remove == first){
           first = after;
       } else{
           before->next = after;
       }
       if (remove == last){
           last = before;
       }else{
           after->prev = before;
       }
       iter.position = after;
       --size;
       delete remove;
       return iter;
   }else{
   throw ElementNotFound();
    }
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::begin(){
return iterator(first);
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::end(){
if(size != 0){
    return iterator(last);
}
throw ElementNotFound();
}

//TODO
template <typename T>
template <typename Predicate>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::find(const Predicate& predicate(const T element))  {//line145
iterator iter;
Node<T>* current = iter.position;
Node<T>* end = iter.last;
for( ; current != end; ++current){
    if( predicate(*current)){
        return current;
    }
}
return end;
}

//TODO
template <typename Compare>
template <typename T>
void List<T>::sort(const Compare& comparer()){//line154
Iterator<T> current = position;
Iterator<T> end = last;
for( ; current != end; ++current){
    if( comparer( *current , *current+1) != true){

    }
}
}

template <typename T>
int List<T>::getSize() const{
return size;
}

template <class T>
List <T>::~List() {
Node <T> * firstNode = first;
while (firstNode != 0)     {
    Node <T> * nextNode = firstNode->next;
    delete firstNode;
    firstNode = nextNode;
}
}

/*Node Class*/
template <typename T> class Node {
private:
T data;
Node* next;
Node* prev;
friend class List<T>;
friend class Iterator<T>;
public:
Node(T element){
    data = element;
    prev = NULL;
    next = NULL;
}
~Node(){}
};

/*Iterator class*/
template <typename T> class Iterator{
private:
Node<T>* position;
Node<T>* last;
friend class List<T>;
public:
Iterator(){
   position = NULL;
   last = NULL;
}
Iterator(Node<T> * source): position(source) { }
T& getElement()const;
bool operator==(Iterator b) const;
bool operator!=(Iterator b) const;
T & operator*();
Iterator & operator++();
Iterator & operator++(int);
~Iterator(){}
};

/*Implimentation of Iterator class function*/
template <class T>
T& Iterator<T>::getElement() const{
if(position != NULL){
   return position->data;
}
else{
   throw ElementNotFound();
}
}

template <typename T>
bool Iterator<T>::operator==(Iterator b) const{
return position == b.position;
}

template <typename T>
bool Iterator<T>::operator!=(Iterator b) const{
return position != b.position;
}

 template <typename T>
  T & Iterator<T>::operator*() {
return position->data;
 }

 template <class T>
 Iterator<T> & Iterator<T>::operator++() {
position = position->next;
return *this;
 }

template <class T>
Iterator<T> & Iterator<T>::operator++(int){
position = position->next;
return *this;
}
```

The messages that I recieve are:

```
C:/Programs/eclipse-with-gcc/eclipse/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/c++/3.4.5/cwchar:161: error: `::swprintf' has not been declared
C:/Programs/eclipse-with-gcc/eclipse/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/c++/3.4.5/cwchar:168: error: `::vswprintf' has not been declared

..\list.h:140: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "List"
..\list.h:154: error: no member function `sort' declared in `List<T>'
..\list.h:154: error: invalid function declaration
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could just put out the problematic part, which can generate the error you are getting. Nobody will go through all of your code.

Comment: What's with the horrendous formatting?

Comment: You are unlikely to get quick help with code that is so unreadable. Clean it up make it look like real code.

Comment: If i would know which part caused the problem it wouldn`t be called a problem.I can`t be more specific.Sorry.

Comment: I'm not sure what `List<T>::iterator List<T>::find(const Predicate& predicate(const T element))` is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you dependent names (`List<T>::iterator`, in particular), and thus [need to use `typename`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600936/officially-what-is-typename-for/1601272#1601272).

Comment: It still not good
..\list.h:140: error: prototype for `typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::find(const Predicate&(*)(T))' does not match any in class `List<T>'
..\list.h:47: error: candidate is: Iterator<T> List<T>::find(const Predicate&(*)(T))
..\list.h:140: error: template definition of non-template `typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::find(const Predicate&(*)(T))'
..\list.h:154: error: no member function `sort' declared in `List<T>'
..\list.h:154: error: invalid function declaration

Comment: @user808176: I think that's a new problem. But I'm not going to sift through your poorly-formatted code (where is your indentation? how do you _read_ this?!) to help you solve compilation errors one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
template <typename Predicate>
List<T>::iterator List<T>::find(const Predicate& predicate(const T element)) {

template <typename Compare>
template <typename T>
void List<T>::sort(const Compare& comparer()) {
```

It looks like you are declaring some kind of function when function argument is expected. Try

```
List<T>::find(const Predicate& predicate)
List<T>::sort(const Compare& comparer)
```

Comment: I have already did it. It was not solved a problem. Compiler asks for constructor or Distructor

Comment: So include headers with Predicate and Compare class definitions.