# When is the "typename" keyword necessary?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, typename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Officially, what is typename for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600936/officially-what-is-typename-for)
>   [Where and why do I have to put the template and typename keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename)

consider the code below:

```
template<class K>
class C {
    struct P {};
    vector<P> vec;
    void f();
};

template<class K> void C<K>::f() {
    typename vector<P>::iterator p = vec.begin();
}
```

Why is the "typename" keyword necessary in this example?
Are there any other cases where "typename" must be specified?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names

Comment: @Martin but the typename in the example is not necessary on the most recent compiler , at least on msvc 19.27.29110 , you can get rid of it and pass compile.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Short answer: Whenever referring to a nested name that is a *dependent name*, i.e. nested inside a template instance with unknown parameter.

Long answer: There are three tiers of entities in C++: values, types, and templates. All of those can have names, and the name alone doesn't tell you which tier of entity it is. Rather, the information about the nature of a name's entity must be inferred from the context.

Whenever this inference is impossible, you have to specify it:

```
template <typename> struct Magic; // defined somewhere else

template <typename T> struct A
{
  static const int value = Magic<T>::gnarl; // assumed "value"

  typedef typename Magic<T>::brugh my_type; // decreed "type"
  //      ^^^^^^^^

  void foo() {
    Magic<T>::template kwpq<T>(1, 'a', .5); // decreed "template"
    //        ^^^^^^^^
  }
};
```

Here the names `Magic<T>::gnarl`, `Magic<T>::brugh` and `Magic<T>::kwpq` had to be expliciated, because it is impossible to tell: Since `Magic` is a template, the very *nature* of the type `Magic<T>` depends on `T` --  there may be specializations which are entirely different from the primary template, for example.

What makes `Magic<T>::gnarl` a dependent name is the fact that we're inside a template definition, where `T` is unknown. Had we used `Magic<int>`, this would be different, since the compiler knows (you promise!) the full definition of `Magic<int>`.

(If you want to test this yourself, here's a sample definition of `Magic` that you can use. Pardon the use of `constexpr` in the specializaation for brevity; if you have an old compiler, feel free to change the static member constant declaration to the old-style pre-C++11 form.)

```
template <typename T> struct Magic
{
  static const T                    gnarl;
  typedef T &                       brugh;
  template <typename S> static void kwpq(int, char, double) { T x; }
};
template <> struct Magic<signed char>
{
  // note that `gnarl` is absent
  static constexpr long double brugh = 0.25;  // `brugh` is now a value
  template <typename S> static int kwpq(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
};
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
  A<int> a;
  a.foo();

  return Magic<signed char>::kwpq<float>(2, 3);  // no disambiguation here!
}
```

Comment: @Nils: `const` wouldn't be valid C++.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I can't understand one last thing: as the name `Magic<T>::kwpq` is dependent from the template parameter `T`, this will be resolved in the second phase of the *two-phase lookup*, right? So why the compiler shouldn't be able to check at that time (when he will be able to determine whether `kwpq` is a template or a type or whatever) if the name is used correctly according to its *tier of entity*?

Comment: @PaoloM: The definition of the member function of the class template `A` have to parse already during the first phase, so you need the disambiguation for the syntax to make sense. In the second phase, we check that the instantiation `Magic<T>` for the concrete type `T` actually has a member `kwpq` that is a function with the appropriate signature. (And thanks for the edit!)

Comment: Just a quick note that I cannot repro any error with new compiler.
Maybe nothing fundamental in this snippet that requires 'typename'?
Visual Studio 2022 builds well without typename/template marked with ^^ above.

Answer (score 11):

The `typename` keyword, is needed because `iterator` is a dependent type on `P`. The compiler can't guess if `iterator` refers to a value or a type, so it assume its a value unless you yell `typename`. It's needed whenever there is a type dependent on a template argument, in a context that either types or values would be valid. For instance, as base classes `typename` is not needed since a base class must be a type.

On the same subject, there is a `template` keyword used to let the compiler know that some dependent name is a template function instead of a value.

Answer (score 8):

The typename keyword is needed whenever a type name depends on a template parameter, (so the compiler can 'know' the semantics of an identifier (*type* or *value*) without having a full symbol table at the first pass).

---

Not in the same meaning, and a bit less common, the *lone typename keyword* can also be useful when using generic template parameters: http://ideone.com/amImX

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

template <template <typename, typename> class Container,
          template <typename> class Alloc = std::allocator>
struct ContainerTests 
{
    typedef Container<int, Alloc<int> > IntContainer;
    typedef Container<std::string, Alloc<int> > StringContainer;
    //
    void DoTests()
    {
        IntContainer ints;
        StringContainer strings;
        // ... etc
    }
};

int main()
{
    ContainerTests<std::vector> t1;
    ContainerTests<std::list>   t2;

    t1.DoTests();
    t2.DoTests();
}
```

Comment: I never knew about "lone typename"before, that's cool!