# C++ member function of class template not recognized

Tags: c++, templates, binary-tree

I'm working on a binary search tree class and implementing a Find operation. There are two versions of the public function, one which returns a const Node* and is const and the other which returns a non-const Node* and is not itself const. Here are the public definitions:

`const Node *Find(const T &t) const { Find(t, m_root); }`

`Node *Find(const T &t) { Find(t, m_root); }`

And here's the definition of the private Find method:

```
template <typename T>
const Node* CTree<T>::Find(const T &t, Node *root) const {
    if (root == 0)
        return Node();
    else if (t < root->m_number)
        Find(t, root->m_ll);
    else if (t > root->m_number)
        Find(t, root->m_rl);
    else
        return this;
}
```

Visual Studio is telling me that "'Find' : member function not declared in 'CTree'". Why would it say that?

Edit to add specifics of error messages:
There are 5 messages for the line of the private method definition starting `const Node*...`

`Missing type specifier - int assumed`

`Syntax error : missing ';' before '*'`

`'T' : undeclared identifier`

`'CTree' : 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'`

`syntax error : missing ',' before '&'`

Then one more error for the closing brace of the definition (this is the one that I believe is causing the other 5):

`'Find' : member function not declared in 'CTree'`

As a note, Visual Studio is not highlighting `Node` in the definition of `Find` as it does elsewhere.

Here's the whole class: http://pastebin.com/JEEZJD4n

Comment: You didn't post any information which could be used to help you. Send whole error message, line on which it occurs. Is it your whole class?

Comment: I edited my question to include the error information. No, this isn't the whole class, but I believe it should be enough to help me figure out the problem.

Comment: There are probably some syntax errors. I can't figure out what is casing the problem. I need at least full class definition for methods and attributes. Something that should compile.

Comment: Ok, I put in a pastebin link to the whole class.

Comment: @spartanhooah JEEZ! you pastebin url is awesome! =)

Comment: Haha, I hadn't noticed that!

Answer (score 1):

Mistake is in method definition (line 93 of pastebin):

```
template <typename T>
const Node* CTree<T>::Find(const T &t, Node *root) const {
```

You don't have any type `Node` in global scope, because your `class Node` in nested. So first fix will be an addition of the parent class qualification:

```
template <typename T>
const CTree<T>::Node* CTree<T>::Find(const T &t, Node *root) const {
```

But, there is another problem: now, compiler cannot parse it right way. You must add `typename` keyword, to indicate a nested type:

```
template <typename T>
const typename CTree<T>::Node* CTree<T>::Find(const T &t, Node *root) const {
```

See "[When is the “typename” keyword necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/when-is-the-typename-keyword-necessary)" for details.

Notes:

- You can avoid any of those problems if you put method definition directly to a class body (depending on your code style).
- You could broadly enrich your coding experience, and make your template coding more productive, if you could use different compilers. Note how `g++` is clearer in this kind of error:

  ```
  main.cpp : At global scope :
  main.cpp : 104 : 7 : error : 'Node' does not name a type
  const Node* CTree<T>::Find(const T &t, Node *root) const
        ^

  main.cpp: At global scope:
  main.cpp:104:7: error: need 'typename' before 'CTree<T>::Node' 
  because 'CTree<T>' is a dependent scope
  const CTree<T>::Node* CTree<T>::Find(const T &t, Node *root) const
        ^
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the help. In my first two C++ classes, I was taught to split the declarations and definitions in general. I've learned about templated functions and classes, but this is my first encounter with a nested class.