# C++ inherit template dependable types

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, using

I have a template and many derived classes. In all of these classes I want to use the template type and some dependent types of it (actually I have many types and many dependent types).

The following approach is quite bad, since I need to manually inherit (with using keyword) all the types from the parent class (see code example):

**EDIT:** I didn't know that it is important that the class where I want to use the types is also a template. I updated the code example accordingly.

```
template<class T>
class A {
  using TBase = T;
  using TDerived = T[10];
}

template<class T>
class B : A<T> {
  // NOTE i want the types TBase and TDerived here and in further children
  using TBase    = A<T>::TBase;
  using TDerived = A<T>::TDerived
}

class C : B<int> {
  // NOTE i want the types TBase and TDerived here and in further children
  using TBase    = B<int>::TBase;
  using TDerived = B<int>::TDerived
}
```

I also thought about templated namespaces so that I could define the types outside of the class - but they don't exist.

Does anyone have a better idea?

**SOLUTION1: fix current approach**
(based on the comments from *Jan Hudec* and the answer from *Oguk*)

1. **public inheritance**
   I forget the keyword `public:` for classes (struct is public by default).
2. **missing `typename`**
   The compiler warning for my (wrong) types where used in the class where misleading (although the ones for the `using` keyword directly hint to the missing `typename keyword`).
   Further notes about when to use `typename` can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7923419/3779655
3. **type interitance**
   When I correctly specify the type (e.g. see *2. missing `typename`*) then I can also use the current class name.

Resulting code:

```
template<class T>
class A {
public:
  using TBase = T;
  using TDerived = T[10];
};

template<class T>
class B : public A<T> {
public:
  // possiblity 1:
  using TBase = typename B::TBase;
  TBase memberB1;
  // possibility 2
  typename B::TBase memberB2;
};

class C : public B<int> {
public:
  // NOTE C is no template -> we don't have to do anything
  TBase memberC;
};
```

**SOLUTION2: trait classes**
(based on the answer from *Oguk*)

1. **use templated trait class instead of namespace**
   This gives pretty much the same functionality.
2. **different availability of type information**
   One thing I didn't think of before is to check which type information is available where and if further characters are needed to retrieve the needed type information from a parent class (see NOTE comments).

See code below:

```
template<class T>
struct TypesContainer {
  using TBase = T;
  using TDerived = T[10];
};

template<class T>
class A {
public:
  // TODO possible to directly inherit all types?
  //using TypesContainer<T>;

  // NOTE this is only possible for methods, not types
  using Types = TypesContainer<T>;
  typename Types::TBase memberA;
};

class B : public A<int> {
public:
  // NOTE here I have all template information via definition (by hand)
  using Types = TypesContainer<int>;
  typename Types::TBase memberB;
};

class C : public B {
public:
  // NOTE here I don't have the type information any more
  using Types = TypesContainer<A::Types::TBase>;
  typename Types::TBase memberC;
};
```

**PROBLEM:**
Is there a way to directly inherit all members of a namespace/class within the class scope (see TODO comment). Using the `using` keyword without assignement operator `=` does only work for *methods* not *namespaces*, *classes* and *types*.

Comment: The class B inherits TBase and TDerived, automatically, you don't have to do anything. But if you inherit `A<int>` privately, they are private, so descendants don't get to see them; you need to inherit publically (you could inherit protected too, if you want, but I am not sure it makes sense).

Comment: Note though that if class `B` was a template and the base was argument dependent, you'd have to qualify the inherited types. But IIRC qualifying them with `B::` should work.

Comment: @JanHudec Thanks for your answers. Sorry that I can't upvote them because I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: `using` should certainly work for types.

Comment: @JanHudec I mean using it without the equality sign like after my TODO comment in solution2 (`using TypesContainer<T>;`). Doing this (with or without the `typename`) results in the compiler error _error: expected nested-name-specifier_!

Comment: _type_ and _type template_ are very different thing. `using` works for type (and function) templates too. But it imports the template, not instance, so `using TypesContainer`. Because you can't import just part of a thing without giving it a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you are otherwise fine with your design, it should work if you inherit the base class publicly. This would work in the code you posted. However, if your example is very simplified, there might be another reason you cannot access the typedefs in your real code: The thing which could cause problems for you is if your derived class is actually *also a templated class* with the type parameter `T`, e.g. `B<T>`. This would make the base class `A<T>` *dependent* and its members would not considered during lookup if you use a non-dependent name (i.e. only `TBase`) to refer to them inside `B<T>`, so they would not be found. Referring to them as `typename A<T>::TBase` would solve that problem by making the name dependent names.

If you want to follow your other idea and have that type information available outside of the class (because it is conceptually more connected to `T` and not so much to the class `A`), instead of the "templated namespaces" you were thinking of, usually, trait classes are used for this purpose:

```
template <class T>
struct MyTraits {
    using TBase = T;
    using TDerived = T[10];
}
```

Then you can access those `using` declarations (or, alternatively, `typedefs`) from anywhere by using `MyTraits<T>::TBase`. This is effectively what you would achieve with a templated namespace. Don't forget to add the `typename` keyword if you use the using/typedef members of `MyTraits` in a dependent context, i.e. `typename MyTraits<T>::TBase`.