# Can't use struct in derived templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, struct, g++

Ok, maybe not the best title, but here's the deal:

I have a templated interface:

```
template<typename T>
class MyInterface
{
public:
    struct MyStruct 
    {
        T value;
    };

    virtual void doThis(MyStruct* aPtr) = 0;
};
```

and an implementation:

```
template <typename T>
class MyImpl : public MyInterface<T>
{
public:
    void doThis(MyStruct* aPtr)
    {
    } // doThis
};
```

However, the compiler complains:

```
In file included from MyTest.cpp:3:0:
MyImpl.h:7:17: error: ‘MyStruct’ has not been declared
     void doThis(MyStruct* aPtr)
```

Why is that?

Comment: Use `typename MyInterface<T>::MyStruct`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following compiled for me:

```
template<typename T>
class MyInterface
{
public:
    struct MyStruct
    {
        T value;
    };

    virtual void doThis(MyStruct* aPtr) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class MyImpl : public MyInterface<T>
{
public:
    void doThis(typename MyInterface<T>::MyStruct* aPtr)
    {
    }
};


int main() {
  MyImpl<int> t;

}
```

The main change is that you need to qualify that the `MyStruct` was defined within `MyInterface<T>`.

Since the compiler cannot determine what kind of identifier is the templated subtype, you must help it using the `typename` keyword. (See [When is the "typename" keyword necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/when-is-the-typename-keyword-necessary) for more details on typename)

Comment: Woohooo! Indeed. Thanks @jsantander.