# Template function return type deduction in C++03

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction, return-type-deduction

I would like to implement the following in C++03:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 convert(bool condition, T2& value)
{
    return condition ? value : conversionFunction(value);
}
```

Except I would  like to call `convert` without having to explicitly specify `T1`. How do I do that?

Comment: if condition holds, then you return value, which must be convertible to T1, right?

Comment: No, it is not necessary that it can be converted.

Comment: The second parameter of "convert" template neither has default nor specified? And we expect  the call convert(x) to be picked up by the template above?

Comment: ... yes? I am not sure what you are implying.

Comment: Why don't use the ternary operator to do that ?

Comment: Actually, I don't really understand your example. `convert` has 1 or 2 arguments ???

Comment: @armundle What is `conversionFunction()`?

Comment: This question would be much stronger if you include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The question and your comments do not quite match, so I cannot really tell if my offered solution will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use a hack. The hack is to defer the conversion until you actually use the return value. The return value is a helper object that allows itself to be converted to something else.

```
template <typename T>
struct ConvertHack {
    T &value_;
    const bool cond_;
    ConvertHack (bool cond, T &value) : value_(value), cond_(cond) {}
    template <typename U> operator U () const {
        return cond_ ? value_ : conversionFunction(value_);
    }
};

template <typename T>
ConvertHack<T> convert(bool condition, T& value) {
    return ConvertHack<T>(condition, value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return types are not deduced by the compiler (this is consistent with overloading being not supported on return types). You have to specify this template parameter explicitly, e.g. by calling

```
convert<Obj>(x);
```

The second template parameter does not have to be specified, it can be deduced even though the first template parameter has been specified explicitly (so always put the template parameters that will need explicit specification before the ones that can be deduced!).

However, that only works if both the return type of `conversionFunction` and `T2&` are convertible to `T1`; since the compiler cannot know what value `condition` has at runtime, it has to ensure that both "branches" of the `?:` are compileable. In that case, use [`typename boost::common_type<T1, ReturnTypeOfConversionFunction>::type`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/common_type.html) as return value. If you cannot easily determine `ReturnTypeOfConversionFunction`, you could use [Boost.TypeOf](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/typeof.html).

If the condition can be evaluated at compile time and depends only on `T2`, you can use template-metaprogramming instead:

```
template <bool condition, typename T2>
struct Converter;

template<typename T2>
struct Converter<true, T2> { // If the condition is true, use this.
    typedef T2 type;
    static type doConvert(T2& value) { return value; }
};

template<typename T2>
struct Converter<false, T2> { // If the condition is false, use this.
    typedef ReturnTypeOfConversionFunction type;
    static type doConvert(T2& value) { return conversionFunction(value); }
};

template <typename T2>
typename Converter</* condition */, ReturnTypeOfConversionFunction>::type
convert(T2& value)
{
    return Converter<condition, T2, ReturnTypeOfConversionFunction>::doConvert(value); 
}
```

In place of `/* condition*/`, the [type traits from Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) might be helpful.

The syntax used for `Converter` is called a partial [template specialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_template_specialization).
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/when-is-the-typename-keyword-necessary) for why `typename` is needed when specifying the return value of `convert`.

Comment: Why template on `Obj`?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the previous version of your answer. Just substitute the desired return type (whatever you want for `T1`).