# How can I implement a class which can passed as a template argument?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I want to implement a class, call it K, which will compile when passed as a template argument for template class C. Here is the code sample below:

```
template <typename T>
class C 
{
    typename T::counter_type counter;
public:
    C() : counter(0) {}
    void Do (T t) 
    {
        if (t>0) ++counter;
    }
};

class K
{

};
```

Can anyone help me to understand the implementation?

Comment: `struct K { typedef some_integral_type counter_type; };` or alternatively `struct K { using counter_type = some_integral_type; };`

Comment: compile, add functionality as requested by the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a template class. The template argument is basically a data type that defines the types of the internal data types.

Think about of an implementation of std::vector. It has an internal array, but of what type? Well, you can specify that type as the template argument.

In your class, you declare counter of the type `typename T::counter_type` (see more about typename here: [When is the "typename" keyword necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/when-is-the-typename-keyword-necessary)), and then you have a constructor which initializes the counter to 0 and a method Do, which takes an argument of type T (specified at object declaration) and does something with it.

See templates as a shorthand. Instead of having:

```
class C_int
{
    int counter;
public:
    C() : counter(0) {}
    void Do (int t) 
    {
        if (t>0) ++counter;
    }
};

class C_long
{
    long counter;
public:
    C() : counter(0) {}
    void Do (long t) 
    {
        if (t>0) ++counter;
    }
};
```

you now have `C<int>` and `C<long>`, respectively.