# I wanted to develop a function which takes a vector of any type and returns a map (similar to Counter in python)

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<class T>
map<T,int> counter(vector<T> a)
{
    map<T,int> b;
    pair<map<T,int>::iterator ,bool> pos; //This line shows compiler message
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();++i)
    {
        pos=b.insert(make_pair(a[i],1));
        if(!(pos.second))
        {
            b[pos.first -> first]++;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

This is code using templates.

```
map<int,int> counter(vector<int> a)
{
    map<int,int> b;
    pair<map<int,int>::iterator ,bool> pos;
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();++i)
    {
        pos=b.insert(make_pair(a[i],1));
        if(!(pos.second))
        {
            b[pos.first -> first]++;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

This is the function if I rewrite for integers alone. Integers code is working fine and first one is not. Can you explain me why it is happening and How can I modify it so I works for every data type?

Comment: Without seeing what errors you get (when posting questions about build error always include the full build log, complete and unedited), but my guess is that you should read [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/when-is-the-typename-keyword-necessary)

Answer (score 2):

When you say "the first isn't working fine" are you implying that it doesn't compile due to some funky error about `iterator`? Inside a template dependent names have to be marked as types using `typename`:

```
pair<map<T, int>::iterator, bool> pos;
```

The name `iterator` is a nested name inside `std::map<T, int>`. You'd just use

```
pair<typename map<T, int>::iterator, bool> pos;
```

instead.

Personally, I'd be inclined to entirely side-step the issue an implement the function like this:

```
template<class T>
std::map<T, int> counter(std::vector<T> const& a)
{
    std::map<T, int> result;
    std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [&](T const& value){ ++result[value]; });
    return result;
}
```

This implementation takes advantage of the fact that `operator[]()` inserts new elements with a value initialized value (i.e., using `T()`). Put differently, when there is on object inside the map, it will return a reference to a zero initialized `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`map<T,int>::iterator` is a *dependent name*, i.e. it is dependent on a template parameter. You need to tell the compiler that it always names a type so that it can be parsed correctly:

```
pair<typename map<T,int>::iterator ,bool> pos;
//   ^^^^^^^^
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for more information about the `typename` keyword and when you need to use it.