# Why is repeating typename keyword in function argument list necessary?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have written a toy program that defines a templated function which takes as an argument a `std::vector<T>` and a `std::vector<T>::size_type`.

Here's the working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> foo(std::vector<T> v, typename std::vector<T>::size_type n) {
    n = std::min(v.size(), n);
    return std::vector<T>(v.begin(), v.begin()+n);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
    v = foo(v, 3);
    for (auto i: v) std::cout << i << " "; std::cout << "\n";
}
```

When I leave out the `typename` before `std::vector<T>::size_type` compilation fails after producing this error:

```
test.cc:5:54: error: ‘std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> >::size_type’ is not a type
 std::vector<T> foo(std::vector<T> v, std::vector<T>::size_type n) {
                                                      ^
```

I wonder why that is? Can someone explain why that `typename` is needed here?

Comment: Also found this to explain this quite nicely: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7923369/1025391

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `typename` because std::vector::size_type is a [depended name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name).

Comment: How were you able to post this after the question was marked duplicate?

Comment: @moooeeeep: The post-disabling is a client-side only function.

Comment: @moooeeeep I'm a hacker...

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry I wasn't aware that you closed it?

Comment: Ah, a race condition!

Comment: @KerrekSB `"You typename" is incidentally the lead single on my new rap album.` I can't hold my guts in my belly dude :))))))