# can't understand a function definition using template

Tags: c++, templates

I know how to use template in C++ but can't understand the code below, especially the last line. It's a operator * overloading for half-precision type. Could someone explain this to me? (Here `detail` is a namespace)

```
    /// SFINAE helper for generic half-precision functions.
    /// This class template has to be specialized for each valid combination of argument types to provide a corresponding
    /// `type` member equivalent to \a T.
    /// \tparam T type to return
    template<typename T,typename,typename=void,typename=void> struct enable {};
    template<typename T> struct enable<T,half,void,void> { typedef T type; };
    template<typename T> struct enable<T,expr,void,void> { typedef T type; };
    template<typename T> struct enable<T,half,half,void> { typedef T type; };
    template<typename T> struct enable<T,half,expr,void> { typedef T type; };
    template<typename T> struct enable<T,expr,half,void> { typedef T type; };
    template<typename T> struct enable<T,expr,expr,void> { typedef T type; };
    template<typename T> struct enable<T,half,half,half> { typedef T type; };
    template<typename T> struct enable<T,half,half,expr> { typedef T type; };
    template<typename T> struct enable<T,half,expr,half> { typedef T type; };
    template<typename T> struct enable<T,half,expr,expr> { typedef T type; };
    template<typename T> struct enable<T,expr,half,half> { typedef T type; };
    template<typename T> struct enable<T,expr,half,expr> { typedef T type; };
    template<typename T> struct enable<T,expr,expr,half> { typedef T type; };
    template<typename T> struct enable<T,expr,expr,expr> { typedef T type; };

.... some codes ...   

template<typename T> typename detail::enable<half&,T>::type operator*=(T rhs) { return *this *= static_cast<float>(rhs); }
```

I understand there are different types of struct enable for different template pairs. But what does the struct enable declarations do above? Is it defining a type inside the structure?(so that that `type` has type T inside the sturct?) and in the template specifier, what does for example  mean? I don't know what expr here is. Is it a type or does it have special meaning?

Comment: it means `enable` has a `type` if it satisfies any of those combinations. this would be used to ensure `operator *=` only allows specific types (looks like `half` and `expr` are the only possibilities)

Comment: @vu1p3n0x why `half` and `expr` the only possibilies?

Comment: because those are the only ones that fit the combinations above. there's only 2 template parameters supplied so the other 2 for `enable` default to `void`, so you're only left with the first 2; `<T,half,void,void>` and `<T,expr,void,void>`

Comment: @vu1p3n0x so, you mean, by the first line, `struct enable {}` exists only when the template is <T, typename, void, void>? and this <T, typename, void, void> applies only to `struct enable {}`? and inside `enable` `type` is defined as `T`.. I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: The comment at the top explain the purpose... Essentially the first line is used except when there is a specialization. And the last line will essentially define the operator for each of the specialization in between. Since the non-specialized template does not define type, it will not be considered for operator *= because of SFINAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, **for this particular** `operator*=` only first 3 lines play some role:

```
template<typename T,typename,typename=void,typename=void> struct enable {};
template<typename T> struct enable<T,half,void,void> { typedef T type; };
template<typename T> struct enable<T,expr,void,void> { typedef T type; };
```

Moreover, you could rewrite it even simpler and get the same result:

```
template<typename T,typename> struct enable {};
template<typename T> struct enable<T,half> { typedef T type; };
template<typename T> struct enable<T,expr> { typedef T type; };
```

The meaning of the operator definiton will not change:

```
template<typename T> typename detail::enable<half&,T>::type operator*=(T rhs) { return *this *= static_cast<float>(rhs); }
```

at compile time translates to one of those two:

```
half& operator*=(half rhs) { return *this *= static_cast<float>(rhs); }
half& operator*=(expr rhs) { return *this *= static_cast<float>(rhs); }
```

Artificially limiting you to use either `half` or `expr` as argument type.

The rest of `struct enable` template specializations are used elsewhere but not applicable for this particular operator.

Comment: And if you try to `*=` with any other type, the expansion of `typename detail::enable<half&,T>::type` will fail, finding no member `type`.

Comment: I didn't know the template specialization and now can understand it. Btw, in the last line, the second `typename` is what I can't understand now. I will read the documents.

Comment: `typename detail::enable<half&,T>::type` basically tells the compiler that `::type` refers to the name of a type defined inside `enable` struct. Otherwise, `enable<half&,T>::type` could mean "address of a static function called `type`" or "static variable called `type`" and that would be ambiguous. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/when-is-the-typename-keyword-necessary) for more details.