# C++ template class's functions

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

The `parent()` function is not letting the code compile; I don't know what's wrong. The compiler is saying: `expected a qualified name after typename`.
The constructor is working however. How to fix this?

```
template<typename T>
class Node {
    public:

    //accessors
    Node<T>* parent() const;

    private:
    T Data;
    Node<T>* Parent;
    std::vector<Node<T>*> Children;

};

template<typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T const & data){
    this->Data = data;
}

template <typename T>
typename Node<T>* Node<T>::parent() const {
    return this->Parent;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need the `typename` in `typename Node<T>* Node<T>::parent() const {
    return this->Parent;
}`?

Comment: I see an odd typename before the return type of parent(). What is the full error message?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two issues.

The first issue is that you're missing the constructor declaration inside of the Node class. The second issue is the use of typename in the signature for parent.

```
typename Node<T>* Node<T>::parent() const
```

Node is not a nested dependent type so the use of typename is incorrect here. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/when-is-the-typename-keyword-necessary) for more information.