# How to apply template template parameters in case of variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I'm working on template `MyTemplate` that is going to be used in following way:

```
using Alias = MyTemplate<std::pair<int, char>,
                         std::pair<int, double>,
                         std::pair<int, unsigned int>>;
```

For now we can assume that `MyTemplate` will take only list of pair types. Moreover, all pair types should have the same first type and second type have to vary.

I want to "catch" the pairs' `first_type` in `MyTemplate`. I came up with following definition:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct MyTemplate
{
   using first_type = std::decay_t<decltype((Ts::first_type, ...))>;
   // ...
};
```

When I use `typename MyTemplate::first_type` in context of different template everything works fine. I only get a warning:

```
warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
    using first_type = std::decay_t<decltype((Ts::first_type, ...))>;
                                                                    ^
```

However, I cannot create instance of `Alias` because I get that error:

```
error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'std::pair<int, char>::first_type'
```

Do you gave any idea for "generic" solution? I can use C+17.

Comment: `std::decay_t<decltype((Ts::first_type, ...))>` doesn't make sense. You use a `,` fold expression, but with a type as an operand?

Comment: It's unclear what you actually want the behavior to be. What is `first_type` supposed to be? You have lots of pairs - what's the actual function you're trying to implement

Comment: The problem is with the "create instance" part, and not with the definition of the templates shown above (although that also has problems of its own). And since the "create instance" part is not shown, the question cannot be answered, but it's most likely [a duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/when-is-the-typename-keyword-necessary), or [of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Comment: Also, is there a reason you don't want to use `MyTemplate<int, char, double, unsigned int>` instead of `MyTemplate<std::pair<int, char>, std::pair<int, double>, std::pair<int, unsigned int>>`? You'll be able to easily generate the list of `pair` types in the template, AND you wouldn't need to extract the first type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For now we can assume that `MyTemplate` will take only list of pair types. Moreover, all pair types should have the same first type and second type have to vary.
>
> I want to "catch" the pairs' `first_type` in `MyTemplate`.

Not sure but it seems to me that your looking something as follows

```
template <typename...>
struct MyTemplate;

template <typename FT, typename ... STs>
struct MyTemplate<std::pair<FT, STs>...>
 {
   using first_type = FT;
 };
```

You can verify

```
using Alias = MyTemplate<std::pair<int, char>,
                         std::pair<int, double>,
                         std::pair<int, unsigned int>>;

static_assert( std::is_same<int, typename Alias::first_type>::value, "!" );
```

This way you also impose that the template parameters of `MyTemplate` are all `std::pairs`s with a common `first_type`.

Otherwise, without template specialization and maintaining you way, you can use `std::tuple`/`std::tuple_element_t`

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct MyTemplate
 {
   using first_type = std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<typename Ts::first_type...>>;
 };
```