# How to use types in a parameter pack?

Tags: c++, c++11, parameter-pack

I'm new to c++11 and trying to make a function that runs objects

```
template<size_t I, typename... T>
void fun() {
    // use T here, may be something like
    // std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<T...>>::type i;
    // i.run();
}
```

I don't know how to use the type in parameter pack, what's the correct grammar for this?

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: can not compile error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'

Comment: Try: `typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<T...>>::type i;`. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/when-is-the-typename-keyword-necessary) why you need `typename`.

Comment: thanks and I have [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658632/how-to-use-a-type-of-typename), can u help me with that, lol