# How to use a type of typename?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm new to C++11 and trying to write a function able to handle dynamic types.

```
#include <functional>
#include <stdio.h>

template <typename T>
struct scase {
  T param;
  std::function<void(T &&)> pc;
  // typedef T type;
  // or
  // using type = T;
  // ?
};

template <size_t I, typename... T>
void docase(std::tuple<T...> &t) {
  auto sc = std::get<I>(t);

  // using casetype = typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<T...>>::type;
  // typename casetype::type ti;
  // ti = sc.param;
  // sc.pc(ti);
}

template <typename... T>
void select(T &&... cases) {
  auto tuple = std::forward_as_tuple(cases...);
  docase<0>(tuple);
}

int main() {
   select(
     scase<int>{123, [](int &&v) {
       printf("%d\n", v);
     }}
   )
   return 0;
}
```

The commented codes cause compiler errors. What's the correct syntax for this?

Edit:

errors are like:

```
error C2825: 'casetype': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
error C2510: 'casetype': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
error C2065: 'type': undeclared identifier
error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'ti'
error C2065: 'ti': undeclared identifier
```

Comment: Please provide the error message(s) you are seeing.

Comment: 1) You have incorrect syntax in `main`, missing a closing `}` and a semicolon. 2) `casetype` is a reference type, namely `scase<int>&`. You need to remove the reference first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the syntax errors in your example:

`casetype` is a reference, thus, you cant use the `::` operator on it.

Change the line to

```
using casetype = typename std::remove_reference<typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<T...>>::type>::type;
```

in order to remove the reference.

Live code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/uCRAlW).

Also you need to change `sc.pc()` to `sc.pc(std::move(ti))`, since your function expects an rvalue reference.

For the first comment block: Both ways to declare the member typedef are valid, though I personally prefer `using type = T`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the exact type of case where `auto` makes life much easier. You can simply do:

```
template <size_t I, typename... T>
void docase(std::tuple<T...> &t) {
  auto sc = std::get<I>(t);

  auto& ti = sc.param;
  sc.pc(std::move(ti));
}
```

If you want `ti` to be a copy of `sc.param` you can just omit the reference from `auto`:

```
template <size_t I, typename... T>
void docase(std::tuple<T...> &t) {
  auto sc = std::get<I>(t);

  auto ti = sc.param;
  sc.pc(std::move(ti));
}
```

If you need to have a separate declaration and assignment then you can use `decltype` instead of `auto`:

```
template <size_t I, typename... T>
void docase(std::tuple<T...> &t) {
  auto sc = std::get<I>(t);

  decltype(sc.param) ti;
  ti = sc.param;
  sc.pc(std::move(sc.param));
}
```

If you need to use the type multiple times you can use `decltype` together with `using`:

```
template <size_t I, typename... T>
void docase(std::tuple<T...> &t) {
  auto sc = std::get<I>(t);

  using casetype = decltype(sc);
  typename casetype::type ti;
  ti = sc.param;
  sc.pc(std::move(sc.param));
}
```

Alternatively you can just skip `ti` completely and pass `param` directly to `sc.pc`:

```
template <size_t I, typename... T>
void docase(std::tuple<T...> &t) {
  auto sc = std::get<I>(t);
  sc.pc(std::move(sc.param));
}
```