# Encountring error: no type named ‘iterator_category’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<std::vector<int> >

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator, type-traits

I am trying to create a program which will sort the sequence on integers based on iterators (whether forward iterator or random access iterator). But I am encountering this error when I am trying to pass `vector`:

> error: no type named ‘iterator_category’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<std::vector<int> >

Same issue I am encountering while passing `forward_list` also:

> error: no type named ‘iterator_category’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<std::forward_list<int> >’

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<forward_list>
#include<iterator>
#include<algorithm>
#include<typeinfo>
using namespace std;

template<typename Ran>
void sort_helper(Ran beg, Ran end, random_access_iterator_tag){
    /*
    Random access iterator version of sort
    */
    sort(beg, end);
}

template<typename For>
void sort_helper(For beg, For end, forward_iterator_tag){
    /*
    The version for forward iterators is almost as simple; just copy the list into a vector, sort, and copy
    back again:
    */
    vector<decltype(*beg)> vec{beg, end};
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), beg);

}

template<class Iter>
void testSort(Iter& c){
    sort_helper(c.begin(), c.end(), typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category{});
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    vector<int> vec = {3, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 88};
    forward_list<int> flst = {6, 4, 6, 1, 4, 77, 1, 23, 2, 4};

    testSort(vec);
    testSort(flst);

    for(auto& x:vec){
        cout<<x<<" ";
    }cout<<"\n";

    for(auto& x:flst){
        cout<<x<<" ";
    }cout<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Not sure of it matters but why `const` in `std::iterator_traits<const Iter>::iterator_category`?

Comment: You need to pass an iterator type to `std::iterator_traits`, you are passing `Iter`, which is the container type.

Comment: You should change the function to `template<class Cont> void testSort(Cont& c)` to help keep that straight.

Comment: Totally unrelated: One of the other included headers must be pulling in iostream for you. You can't count on this forever.

Comment: @NathanOliver can you please elaborate more. What's the issue with code?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes i tried passing `typename Iter:: iterator ` but that's also didn't work.

Comment: As @NathanOliver mentioned, you are passing in a container instance to `testSort`, so `Iter& c` is a bit misleading since `c` is not an iterator, so `std::iterator_traits<Iter>` won't work. Perhaps `std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::begin(c))>` is more successful

Comment: @steyn using `typename Iter::iterator` in `std::iterator_traits` works for me, at least in this example. [demo](https://ideone.com/wPlcwJ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `testSort()` function, the `Iter` template argument (whose name is misleading, BTW) is receiving the *container* type, but `iterator_traits` wants an *iterator* type instead.

This will work in your example:

```
template<class Container>
void testSort(Container& c){
    sort_helper(c.begin(), c.end(),
        typename std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator>::iterator_category{}
    );
}
```

However, that will not work for raw C-style arrays, which don't have `begin()`, `end()`, or `iterator` members.  But this will work for them:

```
template<class Container>
void testSort(Container& c){
    sort_helper(std::begin(c), std::end(c),
        typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::begin(c))>::iterator_category{}
    );
}
```

---

Another problem is, this line also fails to compile:

```
std::vector<decltype(*beg)> vec{beg, end};
```

This is because dereferencing an iterator returns a *reference* to the element being referred to, so `decltype(*beg)` returns a reference type, which prevents the `vector::pointer` and `vector::const_pointer` members from being declarable:

> error: forming pointer to reference type ‘int&’

This will work:

```
std::vector<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*beg)>::type> vec{beg, end};
```

However, you can use `iterator_traits` here instead, which has a `value_type` member:

```
std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<For>::value_type> vec{beg, end};
```

Comment: it will be helpfull if you explain about `typename`, How it acually works. I only used it while declaring template classes and template functions. But here we are using it in different context also. can you plain explain about `typename` in this context.

Comment: @steyn "*it will be helpfull if you explain about `typename`*" - already asked and answered many times before. For instance, see [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/) and [When is the "typename" keyword necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/)