# Create class based on variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Lets imagine that we have several data flows and we need unite them to one. Capacity of flows (and type) is known at application level. So we need class that incapsulates all other classes that relates to each data flow and produces common frame based on return type of data flows. Each data flow class have next interface:

```cpp
// note that there are several classes with similar interface
class FlowOne {
  using return_type = some_data;

  return_type get();
};
```

Main flow class will look like:

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
class Main {
  using return_type = *based on Args::return_type*;
  return_type get();
};
```

So, here is a question: how to define Main::return_type - that should be a tuple of return_type-s from its Args? Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use `auto get()` and let the compiler figure it out?

Comment: Is your goal to get `Main::get` to return a collection of all of the `FlowXXX::get` returns?

Comment: you mean something like `std::tuple<typename Args::return_type ...>` ? Did you try anything?

Comment: yes, you are right @NathanOliver

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Then you probably want `using return_type = std::tuple<typename Args::return_type...>;`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number nope, just because I can't find cases like this in documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand `Args...` to be `std::tuple<Args...>` and declare a member of that type. Now your `Main` class has a tuple of all Flow types:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct Main {
    using tuple_type = std::tuple<Args...>;
    tuple_type members;
```

the next step is to make a `get()` function that returns the `.get()` of all members. This can be achieved with [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) to iterate over the tuple, and call `.get()` on each object. Keep in mind that, if your final `get()` functions return a reference, this `get()` should also return one (meaning `auto&` or `auto&&`).

```
auto get() {
    return std::apply([](auto&&... member) {
        return std::make_tuple(member.get()...);
    }, this->members);
}
```

As you can see, if we say `decltype(get)` on the member function, it will be equal to the `std::tuple` of Flow types:

```
struct FlowOne {
    using return_type = int;

    return_type get() {
        return {};
    }
};
struct FlowTwo {
    using return_type = double;
    return_type get() {
        return {};
    }
};

int main() {
    Main<FlowOne, FlowTwo> main;
    auto get = main.get();

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(get), std::tuple<int, double>>);
}
```

---

if you still wish to define a `Main::return_type`, you can use this `using` statement:

```
using return_type = std::tuple<typename Args::return_type...>;
```

we have to add `typename` here, because `return_type` is a dependant type of `Args`. You can read more about this on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/when-is-the-typename-keyword-necessary?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

[Try out the full code on godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/f67nx9jPd)

Answer (score 1):

This calls all the flows and return a `tuple` with all the return values:

```
template <typename... Args>
class Main 
{
public:
    // Return tuple, with all the results of the Args::get()
    // e.g. if Args is <FlowOne, FlowTwo>, then tuple<int,float>
    using merged_type = std::tuple<decltype(Args::get())...>;
    
    merged_type get()
    {
        return {Args::get()...};
    }
};
```

Here is a full and working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

struct FlowOne 
{
  using return_type = int;

  static return_type get()
  { 
      return 42; 
  }
};

struct FlowTwo 
{
  using return_type = float;

  static return_type get()
  {
      return 42.1;
  }
};

template <typename... Args>
class Main 
{
public:
    using merged_type = std::tuple<decltype(Args::get())...>;
    merged_type get()
    {
        return {Args::get()...};
    }
};

int main()
{
    const auto ret = Main<FlowOne, FlowTwo>().get();
    
    std::cout << std::get<0>(ret) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<1>(ret) << std::endl;
}
```

You can test it here:
https://onlinegdb.com/3nG0ffBUd

Comment: yeah, I see your point, but idea is __return all flow values__ at Main::get() call. Also type of flow data can be same for several flows. Anyway, thanks

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch: Let me know if my update match better your need.