# templated class nested type typename

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, nested-class, typename

I have to declare `Iter` as `typename` but no `typedef`. 
Then, I cannot use `Iter` in my `template` `class` declaration => frustrating :( 
Please teach me how to use `Iter`, or else explain me why C++ is so [*nasty*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085134/why-is-c-relatively-harder-to-use-bad-choice-for-a-beginner)...

```
template <typename T>
struct MyContainer
{
  typedef  std::vector<T>  Vec;
  typename Vec::iterator   Iter;

  void Fo (typename std::vector<T>::iterator);  //ok
  typename std::vector<T>::iterator Ba();       //ok

  void Foo (Iter);   //error: 'Iter' is not a type
  Iter Bar ();       //error: 'Iter' does not name a type
};                   //(gcc 4.1.2)
```

1. Why `typedef` cannot be used to declare `Iter`? Why not?
2. How to use `Iter` within the `template` `class`? (e.g. as function parameter type)

**EDIT** 
 In the instruction `typename Vec::iterator Iter;` the keyword `typename` says `Vec::iterator` is a type (i.e. not a static member function/attribute). Therefore, `Iter` is not declared as a type, but as a variable using the type `Vec::iterator`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `typedef` can be used alongside `typename`. So it becomes:

   ```
   typedef typename vec::iterator Iter;
   ```
2. Just use `Iter` now.

   ```
   template <typename T>
   struct MyContainer
   {
     typedef  std::vector<T>         Vec;
     typedef typename Vec::iterator  Iter;

     void Foo (Iter);   //ok
     Iter Bar ();       //ok
   };
   ```

Comment: perfect :) I have just added in your answer the code source solution :-D thanks ;)

Comment: @olibre Regarding your edit to this answer (which I've rolled back): It is possible to use blockquote within enumerations by indenting twice (4 + 4 = 8 spaces). No need for any unusual enumeration syntax...

Comment: @jogojapan Thank you for your tip/advice :-D

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the previous answer...

```
typename Vec::iterator   Iter;
```

is a valid C++ statement which declares not a type but a variable named `Iter`.

The keyword `typename` was introduced to specify that the identifier that follows is a type. When parsing `Vec::iterator`, the compiler is unable to recognize that `iterator` means a type, because it is *a template-dependent name*. It could be as well a static data member in `Vec`.

[Officially, what is typename for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600936/officially-what-is-typename-for)

Comment: Yes, `typename` and `typedef` declare respectively *variable name* and *variable type*, isn't it?

Comment: @olibre: You're not quite right. I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your reminder: `iterator` could be an attribute or a function...

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
typename Vec::iterator   Iter;
```

Declares a member variable called `Iter`, of type `Vec::iterator` (i.e. `vector<T>::iterator`), and not a type.

Looking at what you did after this you probably meant:

```
typedef  typename Vec::iterator   Iter;
```