# Any way to get associated type from struct?

Tags: rust

This code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct MyNode;
struct MyEdge;

struct Graph<N, E> {
    h: HashMap<N, Vec<E>>,
}

type MyGraph = Graph<MyNode, MyEdge>;

fn main() {

    let x: MyGraph::N;//XXX

    println!("Results:")

}
```

Fails to compile with the error:

```
error[E0223]: ambiguous associated type
  --> /home/xxx/.emacs.d/rust-playground/at-2017-07-26-164119/snippet.rs:21:12
   |
21 |     let x: MyGraph::N;
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^ ambiguous associated type
   |
   = note: specify the type using the syntax `<Graph<MyNode, MyEdge> as Trait>::N`
```

Is there any way to get `N` type from `Graph<MyNode, MyEdge>`?

I created an alias (`type =`) to not duplicate node type definitions,
so it would be great at the point marked `XXX` I could write not `let x: MyNode`but `let x: expression with MyGraph as argument`.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated; why not just `let x: MyNode;`? Are there multiple node types?

Comment: @ljedrz Hmm, to prevent code duplication, such places with `let x: MyNode` a lot in my program, when I change `Node` type of this graph I have to fix all those places.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no associated type parameters in your code. [Associated types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#associated-types) are applicable to traits only, which allow you to write this:

```
trait Graph {
    type Node;
    type Edge;
}
```

In particular, you have ordinary type parameters in the struct (`N` and `E`). Without a common trait, you have to resolve the type manually. It's not something complicated to do here anyway.

```
struct GraphImpl<N, E> {
    h: HashMap<N, Vec<E>>,
}

type MyGraph = GraphImpl<MyNode, MyEdge>;

let x: MyNode;
```

However, if you *do* implement this `Graph` trait for your struct:

```
impl<N, E> Graph for GraphImpl<N, E> {
    type Node = N;
    type Edge = E;
}
```

Then you can retrieve the associated type as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35261912/1233251):

```
let x: <MyGraph as Graph>::Node;
```

[Playground](https://gist.github.com/39acc531e26e79d9888a67e4135ba1f7)