# Why does Visual Studio 2015 fail to compile STL lib with "noexcept" when Juce is present?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, stl, juce

I'm getting many errors in the STL (set, vector, deque, etc.) where the macro `_NOEXCEPT_PO` is used. The same code compiles fine in Visual Studio 2010, whose STL doesn't include `_NOEXCEPT_PO` macros. I've replicated this error across three PCs. Are there additional preproc definitions I need to be aware of?

Error given is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector:852: warning: C4346: 'std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc>::std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc>::_Alty::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value': dependent name is not a type

```
_Myt& operator=(_Myt&& _Right)
    _NOEXCEPT_OP(_Alty::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value
        || _Alty::is_always_equal::value)
    {   // assign by moving _Right
    if (this != &_Right)
        {   // different, assign it
        _Tidy();
        if (_Alty::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value
            && this->_Getal() != _Right._Getal())
            this->_Move_alloc(_Right._Getal());

        _Assign_rv(_STD forward<_Myt>(_Right));
        }
    return (*this);
    }
```

`_NOEXCEPT_OP` is defined as:

```
#define _NOEXCEPT   noexcept
#define _NOEXCEPT_OP(x) noexcept(x)
```

**Edit**:

While working to reduce this to a small example, I found that it was the inclusion of Juce headers that made the difference. Unfortunately the error message wasn't very helpful, so I didn't realize the inclusion of Juce was relevant.

The fix for this particular issue is to define:
`JUCE_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_NOEXCEPT=1`

Comment: This is only a warning, and it looks completely superfluous -- there's no reason for a dependent name to necessarily be a type. I suggest disabling it.

Comment: @Quentin no, it is not superfluous at all. It is juat the Microsoft way of telling you that [you may need the typename keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600936/officially-what-is-typename-for).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m. in a noexcept clause expression?!

Comment: @Yakk Anywhere you miss a required typename keyword. This includes noexcept clause expressions of course, why not?

Comment: @n.m. there isn't a missing typename there though.

Comment: @n.m. `value` is a `bool`, not a type, and that's perfectly fine. `typename` would actually break it. But I get where you're coming from -- they *also* have an "extension" that makes `typename` optional.

Comment: @Quentin There are lots of errors, too. All of them associated with a _NOEXCEPT_OP line.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this particular issue is to define: `JUCE_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_NOEXCEPT=1`