# Error in declaring parameter : template argument for template type parameter must be a type; did you forget 'typename'?

Tags: c++, templates

I have been trying to make this code to work, but I keep getting the error

> template argument for template type parameter must be a type; did you forget 'typename'?

```
template <typename T>
class Templated_Class {


  std::unique_ptr<
      folly::NotificationQueue<T>::Consumer,
      folly::DelayedDestruction::Destructor>
      xyz;
};
```

From what I read [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPSQF_9.0.0/com.ibm.xlcpp111.aix.doc/language_ref/keyword_template_qualifier.html), *If the name of a member template specialization appears after a ., ->, or :: operator, and that name has explicitly qualified template parameters, prefix the member template name with the keyword template.*

I tried to follow this advice, but this error does not go away.
What am I doing wrong ? Please note that I am new in modern c++ , and learning curve for c++ is not the easiest to tackle.

Comment: How have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Officially, what is typename for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600936/officially-what-is-typename-for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without complete code a definitive answer isn't possible, however, looking at what you have I would expect changing:

```
folly::NotificationQueue<T>::Consumer,
```

to:

```
typename folly::template NotificationQueue<T>::Consumer,
```

to be where you want to start looking.
typename folly::DelayedDestruction::Destructor>