# template vector

Tags: c++, templates, boost, vector, tuples

I'm trying to implement a function that allows me to make a call like this

```
// veca is a vector of tuples in my case
columnViewOfTuple<0>(veca);
```

I implemented such function as follows

```
template<int N>
struct myfunction {
    template<typename T, typename R>
    std::vector<R> operator() (T& container)
    {
        std::vector<R> myvector;
        for(typename T::iterator it = container.begin(); it!=container.end(); it++)
            myvector.push_back((R)(*it).template get<N>());
        return myvector;
    }
};
```

whenever I call myfunction<0>(vec5), where vec5 is some vector of tuples, it says

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:156: error: conflicting declaration 'myfunction<0> vec5'
main.cpp:155: error: 'vec5' has a previous declaration as 'main()::vec1_t vec5'

Do you guys know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want the int N as a template parameter instead of a function parameter?

Comment: See, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600464/

Comment: it's a requirement. I need N as a template parameter

Comment: Normally you'd want `myfunction<0>()(vec5);`: `myfunction` isn't a function, it's a class: you have to instantiate it before you can call `operator()`. But I'm not sure it will work because I haven't tried it. I don't think the template parameter R can be deduced, so actually you need `myfunction<0>().operator()<R>(vec5);`, where R is replaced by the value type of `vec5`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop should be

```
    for(typename T::iterator it = container.begin(); it!=container.end(); it++)
        myvector.push_back((R)(*it).template get<N>());
```

Otherwise, the compiler will treat `T::iterator` as a non-type (at parse-time, it does not yet know what `T::iterator` is going to be later!) and will likely parse it as the sole constituent of an expression. The `it` that then follows is nonsense for the compiler so it expects a `;` before it.

`typename` is used to tell the compiler that a certain qualified name is intended to denote a type instead of a value (function / static data member / etc).

The second issue, which is solved by adding `template` is of similar kind. It tells the compiler that `get` is a template and thus that `<N` is not a comparison against `N`, but the start of a template argument list.

Comment: +1 for that template piece (and a good answer overall). Sadly, I didn't know this myself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use typename in front of `T::iterator`. So say `typename T::iterator`.

**Edit1 including `template` as indicated by Johannes to prevent misinformation.**

So, your code should be like this:

```
template<int N>
struct myfunction {
    template<typename T, typename R>
    std::vector<R> operator() (T& container)
    {
        std::vector<R> myvector;
        for(typename T::iterator it = container.begin(); it!=container.end(); it++)
            myvector.push_back((R)(*it).template get<N>());
        return myvector;
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you, that was helpful. However, I tried to use the function